# Is there a way to describe unique sequence per each row in Spring Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, flyway, composite-key

I've tried using composite keys - but:

1. Composite keys doesn't work with auto generation
2. @IdClass is broken ([long class couldn't be constructed by Spring](https://pastebin.com/kzbSH34D))
3. @EmbeddedId works but №1 issue is still there

Basically what i want to do, is make unique sequence per row (board link), like this:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| post_id | thread_id | board_link |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 |         1 | board_1    |
|       2 |         1 | board_1    |
|       3 |         1 | board_1    |
|       1 |         2 | board_2    |
|       2 |         2 | board_2    |
|       3 |         3 | board_2    |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE, PostgreSQL 12.3-2 (9.6 testcontainers) and 6.3.2 flyway-core. All through gradle.

Comment: does ```post_id``` increment seperately for every unique ```board_link```. As far as I know using ```@GeneratedValue``` you cannot do this task.

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what you try to achieve? THis looks a table with references to other tables. So all the columns are foreign keys to other tables. If you want to make sure each row is unique add a unique constraint over all 3 rows.

Comment: @PLYSHKA, Do you really have to do this task using ```Hibernate```. You can do this using ```Postgresql``` itself as well.

Comment: It's table just for representing what i want to do, not actual table. This is my actual migration right now: https://pastebin.com/JmcfvisX .


@Abdusoli Not sure what you meant by that, i'm open for suggestions other than that. 


What i'm trying to do is 1 board - 1 sequence for posts (aswell as for threads, because first post (main) in thread should math thread id)

Comment: The main issue is that hibernate can't paste to table automatically (assuming that there is a separate PostPk class for @EmbeddedId in Post. It gives null constraint on primary composite key (null on id)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GeneratedValue` annotation and set the strategy as `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Comment: I haven't tried exactly like this (only with `GenerationType.IDENTITY`), but i don't use auto-generation by hibernate, only validation, so i have to do this in SQL migration too.
When i try to save value without id (part of composite key) it gives me not null constraint error from postgres driver.
Also @Id annotation isn't allowed inside @EmbeddedId object

Comment: Actually, this is an example, so you can remove the ID annotation.
The `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is used with Mysql and the `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` is used with PostgreSQL.

Comment: You can check the following link and there are some other types for SEQ generation:  https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-postgresql-5-things-need-know/

Comment: Sequence didn't help, as i said - you can't autogenerate value for composite keys...
https://pastebin.com/eifCCUVL - stack trace

Comment: I just noticed that migration did put there an object with sequence number, but it failed when i tried to put it with hibernate/spring, interesting